# Adjacency Matrix From a Maze

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, maze, heuristics

I would like to implement an algorithm that would give me the adjacency matrix of the checkpoints (A,B,C,etc...) given a maze stored in a char[][] array.

My first idea was to use a DFS algorithm to find if a given pair of checkpoints were adjacent.

But having been stuck on it for the past 3 days to implement it (I am a beginner to those concepts), I would like to know if a BFS would be the best way to solve that problem.

And if not, what would be a suitable implementation? 
Thanks you.

Here is a sample maze where # represent walls and . represent steps (i.e 2 steps are required to go from A to B).:

```
# A # # # # # #
# . # # # # # #
# B . . . C D #
# . # # # . # #
# E F # # . # #
# . # # # . # #
# G . . . H . I
# . # # # # # #
# . # # K # # #
# . . . J . L #
# # # # # # # #
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use a regular bfs implementation but didn't manage to make it work for my specific problem as when you de-queue an element, if this element is the one you want (i.e the second checkpoint) it will stop, but doesnt take into account what are the previous nodes/steps that you've been through @MaruthiAdithya